# NSString and UILabel in separate classes

Tags: objective-c

I really don´t know what I´m doing wrong here. I have a separate class (Condition.m) where I have the following method: forcastText is an NSString (property, retain)

```
- (void)TheRightText {
        labelText = @"VISUAL";
}
```

In WXController.m:s viewDidLoad I do this to print "Visual" in a label:

```
     [Condition TheRightText];
     [label1 setText:(Condition.labelText)];
```

All I get is (null) from Condition.labelText. What´s wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your interface file looks like but there is no such a thing as (property, retain). It should be:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *labelText;
```

In Condition.h
And when you want to access it you should use

```
self.labelText = @"VISUAL";
```

After that when you want to read it in WXController.m your code should looks like:

```
Condition *condition = [[Condition alloc]init];
[condition TheRightText];
[label1 setText:(condition.labelText)];
```

Hope this help.